# Slideshow with jmpress.js not working in FF

Tags: firefox, slider

I am trying to use this [slider](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/index3.html)

Unfortunately sliding effects doesn't work on my firefox(31). Does anyone know where can be problem?

All the new css3 transforms should firefox support so I don't see problem in this.

Update:also [jmpress.js](http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js/#/home) animations doesn't work for me in firefox

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found a [solution](https://github.com/jmpressjs/jmpress.js/issues/154) if anyone else will have same problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this link a bit? It's difficult to extract exactly what the fix was in the list of comments on github.

Comment: sorry I can't remember now, it's been a long time. But just try all advices in that link and you will find one which gonna work.